# can ping website but not enter it

Tags: windows, iis, nslookup

I currently have two server {A;B}. A is hosting a IIS webpage, and B is trying to access it. 
I am able to access the page within server A (No problem since it is hosted there)..
I have altered the host file in server B, so the page I am trying to acess points to server A.

This doesn't seem to be enough though, as I am not able to enter the page from server B.

- I can ping the server A from server B
- I can ping the website from server
- nslookup website shows that server B is trying to connect to the incorrect server?

Why it is trying to access the wrong server? I don't know? 
The host file points to the server A - so why does nslookup say it point to a different server?

Comment: nslookup for server a seem to point the same incorrect server.. So that cannot be the problem?

Comment: just telnet on port 80 from server B to server A IP address.  May be server A firewall is blocking the outside connections.

Comment: Can you logon to server B and try to open the website on server A? This should show you what is happening

Comment: Run Jexus Manager Binding Diagnostics on server A to learn if you miss anything, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

NSLookup does not check the hostsfile, but your DNS server by default. Do you get the correct IP adress when pinging server A? PING should adhere to the HOSTS file.